# What should be changed in the regex in order to allow only alphabets with spaces anywhere?

Tags: regex, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

```
@Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$",message="Username must be alphanumeric with no spaces")
```

I would like to change the regex in order to allow alphabets with spaces any where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then add `\s` to your character class

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$
```

`\s` signifies space in regex. You can use a a literal space also like `^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$`

Comment: Note that the explanation of `\s` is not completely correct.  The `\s` stands for the whitespace character class, which includes `[\r\n\t\f ]` (generally speaking), not just a literal space.  Therefore, if the OP wanted **only** spacebar spaces, and not things like tabs or newlines, the second regex here should be used and **not** the first.  Example with a tab and newline:  http://regex101.com/r/cW1gT5/2

Answer (score 2):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$
```

Use this to allow spaces as well.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/29

Answer (score 1):

`a-z` allows lowercase letters, `A-Z` capital letters, `0-9` numbers from 0-9 and `\s` for space.

gave you the weapon, fight the war